# Creating folders using PHP in google docs

Tags: php, rest, gdata-api, gdata, google-docs

Currently I am working on a project integrating google docs to my application using php. However, there is only version1 for the php and I am not well-versed with REST web service. And I am required to create folder using the api. I wonder any people manage/know how to do it? Below is the protocol for the creation of the folder. If anyone know how to do it, I would be glad if you can assist me. Thank you in advance.

```
POST /feeds/default/private/full HTTP/1.1
Host: docs.google.com
GData-Version: 3.0
Authorization: <your authorization header here>
Content-Length: 245
Content-Type: application/atom+xml

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind"
      term="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#folder"/>
  <title>Example Folder</title>
</entry>
```

Comment: use `curl` or `RESTclient` (maybe http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5480-PHP-Send-Web-services-requests-to-REST-servers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/Using-curl-and-PHP-to-talk-to-a-REST-service

If you need more information after this take a look at the functions in the PHP manual for [CURL](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/Using-curl-and-PHP-to-talk-to-a-REST-service).